# AWS EMR | Total numbers of Mappers when pointing to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am bit curious to know how EMR cluster will decide total number of mappers, if we are triggering Hive workloads pointing to S3 location. In S3 data is not stored in form of blocks, so which component will create Input splits and assigns mapper to it?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to find the number of mappers needed to process your input data files:

1. The number of mappers depends on the number of Hadoop splits. If your files are smaller than HDFS or Amazon S3 split size, the number of mappers is equal to the number of files. If some or all of your files are larger than HDFS or Amazon S3 split size (fs.s3.block.size) the number of mappers is equal to the sum of each file divided by the HDFS/Amazon S3 block size.

The examples below assume 64 MB of block size (S3 or HDFS).

**Example 1:** You have 100 files of 60 MB each on HDFS = 100 mappers. Since each file is less than the block size, the number of mappers equals the number of files.

**Example 2:** You have 100 files of 80 MB each on Amazon S3 = 200 mappers. Each data file is larger than our block size, which means each file requires two mappers to process the file. 
100 files * 2 mappers each = 200 mappers

**Example 3:** You have two 60 MB, one 120 MB, and two 10 MB files = 6 mappers. The 60 MB files require two mappers, 120 MB file requires two mappers, and two 10 MB files require a single mapper each.

2. An easy way to estimate the number of mappers needed is to run your job on any Amazon EMR cluster and note the number of mappers calculated by Hadoop for your job. You can see this total by looking at JobTracker GUI or at the output of your job. Here is a sample of job output with the number of mappers highlighted:

> 13/01/13 01:12:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0 13/01/13 01:12:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms) =0 13/01/13 01:12:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Rack-local map tasks=20 13/01/13 01:12:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: 
>   Launched map tasks=20 
>   13/01/13 01:12:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=2329458

Reference: [Amazon EMR Best Practices](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-amazon-emr-best-practices.pdf)

Comment: Does S3 stores the data in form of blocks? if yes, what is the default block size? Is there a way to alter the block size?